# Why does flac http streaming not work?

Tags: windows, http, streaming, directshow, multimedia

I have simple http streaming application that takes GET URL request and returns HTTP "content-type" header and then requested file data. It runs on localhost http server.

Thus I can listen in player for (e.g.)

http://localhost:8080/music/metallica.mp3

It is played like a usual http stream in any player (VLC, MPlayer, WMP, Winamp).

However, why I try to stream FLAC in this way it doesn't work in MPlayer and WMP (I use content type "audio/flac").

As far as I understand the problem is with DShow filters (Graph Builder can't locate correct source filter and/or connect it to flac decoder).

Can't anyone give a hint on where shall I dig, before I start DShow filters debugging? :)

**UPD:**

I've found that setting exact stream size (thru content length) solving the problem.
However, I would prefer not doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming from network resource is different from streaming from a file. A streaming protocol is assumed to be implemented between server and player host and Windows does not offer a great support for streaming client within DirectShow API out of the box: you need an additional filter which supports this kind of streaming.

Comment: hm... i'm doing streaming via http :) mp3 works fine, flac not. So I assume flac decoder just can't get connected to source filter mp3 decoder uses... but how to solve this. I don't want to write source filter because it is platform dependent (streaming app is in java) and it requires installation.

Comment: There are ways to stream via HTTP: it could be RTSP/RTP protocol tunnelled through HTTP, it could be accessing a network resource in a way as if it was a remote file. DiretShow has no stock filters for HTTP streaming.

Comment: Sounds logical, however dshow is able somehow to play mp3 files from pure Apache without any kind of applied protocol on top of http transport. GraphEdit proves this, when I feed it with http url it renders graph correctly.

Comment: Don't know if this exactly url is pure-http however it works fine too: http://listen.42fm.ru:8000/stealkill

Moreover, as I recently found even flac works fine thru http. It start playing without getting whole file from the server (i.e. we can call it "streaming" :)). However, it won't work if stream size is unknown...

Comment: It does not work fine. It might be working in Windows XP through a filter no longer supported, or you have a third party filter installed.

Comment: The URL is still playable in Windows Media Player in Windows 7, but it takes place outside DirectShow: WMP uses Media foundation to play it.